# Refresh activity layout using android databinding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

After changing the language of the application, i need to reset every textview, button etc. within the activity. Is there an easy way to do this using android databinding library, rather than reseting all the view texts or refreshing the activity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283909/two-way-databinding-not-updating-ui) link, You will surely get an idea on how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, i found an easy way:

After changing the language, calling *binding.invalidateAll();* function will reload all the views and set the new strings. For this to work, i needed to set the label of the views inside *@{...}* tag like @{@string/some_string}.